# How to use text as background opposed to using an image? CSS

Tags: html, css, html-select

Just like the Title says, "How to use text as a background instead of an image?"

I'm making a little application, that I personally think is cool but will probably be a waste of peoples time, and am altering the button in the drop down button to an upside down triangle using this html code ▼ . I'm not talking about setting the z-index or anything just simply placing a character for the little arrow. I thought about leaving it blank but I don't think users would understand that they are supposed to use the menu if I did so. Therefore I'm going to use the upside down triangle.

My CSS for the drop-down list is set up like this

```
select {
 border: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: no-repeat right #ffffff;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: '';
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use use text as the background with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191464/is-there-a-way-to-use-use-text-as-the-background-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

Put the text inside an HTML tag with class .text-background, set CSS styles to

```
.text-background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and set z-index to the elements you want to be on top of the text with z-index higher than 1.

edit:

If you know what the size of the select element is, you probably want to position that text over the dropdown. This however will block the button.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NicotineLL/rDeXZ/)

If you want better looks and functionality you can use a 3rd party libraries such as [this](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/) or [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns).

edit 2:
I just found this CSS only solution given by [Danield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968900/1419575) that's probably going to suite your needs better.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968900/1419575

Comment: It's to replace the drop down button in the select tag. So Wouldn't I have to position the right way which would change from screen resolutions?

Comment: I could just use an image but I'm not to fond of using graphics on the web page. I prefer to just mark everything up

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want to do here, can you submit a jsfiddle demo so I can give you more accurate answer. If you want to put the text over an HTML form (such as a dropdown menu) you can actually position it absolutely over the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, [as suggested by Paulo Bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191464/is-there-a-way-to-use-use-text-as-the-background-with-css/1191472#1191472):

**JS Fiddle**
[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/guEA8/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="background">
Text to have as background
</div>
Normal contents
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
position: relative;
}
#background{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -1;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I know what you guys are saying but this is for the drop down list for the <select> tags I'm simply "hacking" away the old bulky gross drop down arrow, that I personally think HTML5 and CSS3 should have had alternative options implemented, for the upside down utf-8 arrow

Comment: check this fiddle if you want anything like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/r9Dyq/2/

or if you can explain a bit more.

Comment: I really don't like how you're copy/pasteing answers without using proper source.