# Fill the div with some text instead of using background

Tags: css

Is there any possibility to fill the text as the background for the div in css3 or css4?

```
div{
  background: 'some text' repeat;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Short answer: no. BUT you could fake it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191464/is-there-a-way-to-use-use-text-as-the-background-with-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body {
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='20px' width='70px'><text x='0' y='10' background-color='grey' fill='grey' font-size='10'>Some text</text></svg>");
}
```

There is no direct property, using SVG you can achive this.

refer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7yhaos3/6/) for fiddle

Comment: I don't know svg, but its great to use. thanks.

Comment: It's worth to note that it works on [IE9 and above](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css).

Comment: this is what you expected??

Comment: yes, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: SVG has support in IE9+ :)