# Css class as background

Tags: html, css

I have some shape as a css id, for example:

```
#triangle-bottomleft { 
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-bottom: 100px solid blue; 
   border-right: 100px solid transparent; 
}
```

I'd like to use it as a repeated-background of text.

```
<h1 class="myClass">My text.</h1>


.myClass {
    background: triangle-bottomleft;
}
```

How to deal with it?

Comment: according to w3c (http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss) your code is not a corrected format.

Comment: It's not possible to use another class as a property value.

Comment: @saina ".myClass {
    background: triangle-bottomleft;
}" is only as an example here. I'd like to put my background-id somewhere in .myClass definition.

Comment: If it can't be property value how to make triangles as h1 text background?

Comment: Would be quite fantastic if something along the lines of that actually was possible :)

Comment: okay thanks @lwozniak, but it is new type of code for me.. still i m learning..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** as i just saw you would like to use a class as property. i don't think that is possible by now. neither can u use actual "text" as a background value.

What you *could* do is use another container containing text as a background `position: absolute` `z-index: -1` container seen here: 
[LINK TO SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191464/is-there-a-way-to-use-use-text-as-the-background-with-css)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background">
    Text to have as background
    </div>
    Normal contents
</div>
And then the CSS:

#container {
   position: relative;
}

#background {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

**EDIT OVER**

If you use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) you could simply `@extend .className` inside any other class. doesn't work inside media-queries tho. and furthermore you would need [GRUNT](http://gruntjs.com/) to compile your SASS files properly.

> > @extend
>
> There are often cases when designing a page when one class should have
>   all the styles of another class, as well as its own specific styles.
>   The most common way of handling this is to use both the more general
>   class and the more specific class in the HTML. For example, suppose we
>   have a design for a normal error and also for a serious error. We
>   might write our markup like so:

[taken from here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend)

Comment: I don't get it how SASS is useful over here

Comment: edited. wasn't paying attention to the actual question :P thought he would like to use a class inside another class more than once without writing the whole code again. that's where SASS would come to play