# Fill the browser window with random digits

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to fill the visible window in a webpage with random digits. The way I am currently trying to do this involves a long string of random digit first, and then using the following property on a div:

```
 #mydiv{
      font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
      word-break: break-all;
      font-size: 3em;
      color: #202020;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y:hidden;
      }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4ztpbnm0/1/

It works(ish) on Chrome, but it takes a very noticeable amount of time to reflow after resizing the browser window. Is there any way to make this seamless?

Comment: "but it takes a very noticeable amount of time to reflow after resizing the browser window. Is there any way to make this seamless?" - I haven't noticed that while resizing the jsfiddle you provided.

Comment: Did you noticed that your final string length is `11072`, not 173*6?

Comment: @nicael, this rerender freeze appeared only with horizontal resize.

Comment: @vp_arth That's what I've tried, but the window seems to be resizing smoothly, as usual.

Comment: @nicael, what browser/version you use? I get about 5sec of freeze with chromev51

Comment: @vp_arth Safari 9.1.1. Or does OP mean it only lags for Chrome?

Comment: Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit) running on Ubuntu

Comment: Horizontal resizing is very smooth on Firefox 44.0 running on the same machine, but the height constraint is not respected.

Comment: If I force the height with max-height firefox is still smooth, and chrome still lags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `overflow-wrap: break-word` instead of `word-break: break-all`.

https://jsfiddle.net/746g71wb/

`word-wrap` was recently renamed to `overflow-wrap`, so to support other browsers you may want to specify both:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Possibly relevant Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=591793

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an SVG background image (supported by [all current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css)). You can add as many 'random' digits to the SVG tile as you like to make it look convincing:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='400px' width='385px'><text x='0' y='0' font-size='40px' font-family='monospace' fill='%23202020'><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>0011010101010100</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>0101001010100101</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>1010101000010001</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>0101010101000100</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>0010110101010101</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>0101000010101010</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>1010101101110101</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>1010010010010110</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>0100110101010101</tspan><tspan x='0' dy='40px'>1011100010111001</tspan></text></svg>");
}
```

Its performance is super fast even on an ~8 year old laptop. If you are serious about randomness, generate the SVG via JavaScript and fill it with completely random digits.

See also [Is there a way to use use text as the background with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191464/is-there-a-way-to-use-use-text-as-the-background-with-css)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of concatenating the string, use an array. It's much faster.

```js
bgtext = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 173; ++i) {
  bgtext.push(Math.random() < 0.5 ? '1' : '0');
}

for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
  bgtext.push(bgtext.join(''))
};

function loadbg() {

 bgtext = bgtext.join('');

  document.getElementById('background').innerHTML = bgtext;
}
loadbg();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="background">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm aware this will make the loading a little bit faster, but this isn't what I'm concerned about. Resizing is still super slow.

Comment: no difference, if not slower. Issue is not while generate, it's while rerender view on resize. No js code running here.